# I have to make 3 objects in blueJ and call the display() but i couldnot even make object. Please see the result of codes

Tags: java

I have to make 3 objects in blueJ and call the display() but i couldnot even make object. Please see the result of codes

```
public class Project
{
  String Name;
  String deadline;
  String Version;
  double cost;
  public Project(String Name,String deadline,double cost){
      this.Name=Name;
      this.deadline=deadline;
      this.cost=cost;
   }
   public void display(){
    System.out.print("Name of project is: "+this.Name);
    System.out.print("Deadline of the project is: "+this.deadline);
    System.out.print("Cost of the project is: Rs."+this.cost);
   }


}
```

*while trying to make object it appears a dialogue box where it says ;expected even after entered so i don't know where to enter*

Comment: The title should shortly resumt the issue, not detail it ;)

Comment: How do you try ti create the object, please share the code, share the main

Comment: Simlply from the feature of blue j. By right clickling and choosing

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question correctly... if you want to create three objects of the class and want to output the properties passed in the constructor, you can do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
    Project pro1 = new Project("Project - X", "deadline - x", 55.12);
    Project pro2 = new Project("Project - Y", "deadline - y", 23655.2);
    Project pro3 = new Project("Project - Z", "deadline - z", 100.00);
    projects.add(pro1);
    projects.add(pro2);
    projects.add(pro3);

    display(projects);


}
static void display(List<Project> pro) {
    for (Project project : pro) {
        System.out.println("Name of project is: " + project.name);
        System.out.println("Deadline of the project is: " + project.deadline);
        System.out.println("Cost of the project is: Rs." + project.cost);
        System.out.println();

    }
}

public static class Project {
    String name;
    String deadline;
    String version;
    double cost;

    public Project(String name, String deadline, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.deadline = deadline;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

Output:

> Name of project is: Project - X
>   Deadline of the project is: deadline - x
>   Cost of the project is: 55.12
>
> Name of project is: Project - Y
>   Deadline of the project is: deadline - y
>   Cost of the project is: 23655.2
>
> Name of project is: Project - Z
>   Deadline of the project is: deadline - z
>   Cost of the project is: 100.0